# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function when create child class in parent

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typeerror

There are 2 classes (abstract and concrete).
Abstract one creates concrete (i know it is not the best idea, but just for example). In other languages it works just perfectly, but not in javascript. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
import {Archer} from "@/Entities/Army/Individual/Archer";

export abstract class Unit {
    public abstract bombardStrength(): number;

    public abstract defensiveStrength(): number;

    public getComposite(): void {
        console.log(new Archer());
    }
}
```

```
import {Unit} from "@/Entities/Army/Unit";

export class Archer extends Unit {
    bombardStrength(): number {
        return 40;
    }

    defensiveStrength(): number {
        return 35;
    }
}
```

Why js crashes with this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot import child class in parent class file, because import will lead class declaring, but both have not declared yet.

You need to take `getComposite` out from `Unit` to a separate file.

Comment: This is really strange behavior. In other languages doing this way is completely fine.

Comment: Also, I find the error message rather cryptic.

Comment: wow, what a cryptic error message! thanks god I found your reply, without it it would have probably take me hours to find the issue! (large project, didn't know I have a circular dependency issue).

Answer (score 0):

The class which implements an abstract class must call super() in the constructor. This is how abstract class works in typescript.

```
import {Unit} from "@/Entities/Army/Unit";

export class Archer extends Unit {
 constructor(){
 super();    
}
bombardStrength(): number {
    return 40;
}

defensiveStrength(): number {
    return 35;
}
}
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: It's not a must though. If you omit the constructor, one will be added that automatically calls super()

Comment: It did not help